# Проблема при первом запуске Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: java, sql, javafx, sqldeveloper

Проблема точно такая же, как описана здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484814/oracle-sql-developer-problem-initializing-welcome-page

Действительно был установлен Open JDK. Я установил Oracle Java 8 JDK, выбрал после этого новую версию java, проверил переменныу среды, но все равно проблема осталась - sql developer запускается с той же ошибкой - Problem initializing the JavaFX runtime. This features requires JavaFX.
Подскажите, кто знает, пожалуйста, что я упустил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Посмотрите в файле "КАТАЛОГ_ГДЕ_УСТАНОВЛЕН_ВАШ_SQLDEVELOPER"/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf значение SetJavaHome.
2. Для Windows можно использовать версию "with JDK included" [Oracle SQL Developer Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)
3. Насколько я понимаю, JavaFX нужна только для Welcome Page, для работы самого SQL Developer это не надо. Попытайтесь как-то "обойти" эту страницу.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если ответ помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его как "правильный". Это поможет другим пользователям SO находить правильные ответы.